# Wrap created elements in a div

Tags: jquery

I created 4 buttons with a loop, but I want them all to be in a parent div. How do I do that?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var linkNumber = i + 1;
        $('body').append('<button>' + linkNumber + '</button>');
    }
```

I tried adding `<div>` before `<button>` but that just creates a div for each button individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the div then the buttons :

```
var div = $('<div>').appendTo(document.body);
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     var linkNumber = i + 1;
     div.append('<button>' + linkNumber + '</button>');
}
```